ubuntu 22.04 ssh keys aren't stored
I got a new laptop with ubuntu 22.04 and I had to configure the ssh to work with gitlab repos, I followed the generate ssh key pairs from the docs and I used the ED25519.
as I said, I followed the steps and added the key into my gl account. now, everytime I try to clone a repo or run git push or git pull I get this error:
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519 "/home/abar/.ssh/id_ed25519" from agent: agent refused operation
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey)

note: trying to ssh into a remote server gives me the same error, is not related with gl.
runnign these commands (from the gl docs) I can work connect to gitlab in the session I have open in the terminal, opening a new session does not know about it and I have to run again these commands.
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add <directory to private SSH key>

the docs also suggest to add the ~/.ssh/config with these lines (it does not work)
Host gitlab.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_com_rsa

I asked chatgpt about it and it suggests 2 things:

run ssh-add -l to verify if my key exists. OK, it returns the value. it also suggests to run the eval and ssh-add the key

add the eval and ssh-add into .zshrc file. that's not a great deal as everytime I have to enter the passphrase...


Another thing I've checked is the content of $SSH_AUTH_SOCK and it returns /run/user/1002/keyring/ssh.
in the old laptop I was using ubuntu 22.04 and I didn't have these issues, I've checked permissions, config files and they're the same.
I don't know what to do to fix this issue.

Okay, I don't know exactly how but I read the docs from GitHub to compare them with GitLab and the steps to add & configure an ssh key.
The steps are the same but I noticed that GitHub adds these lines into the config file for github.com.
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes

I wanted to give it a try and added AddKeysToAgent yes. I closed the terminal and now every project cloned from GitLab works and I don't need to execute the ssh agent and add my key every time.
